# Adding the same object to a QTabWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a few toggleable `QPushButton`s that I need to add to all tabs of a `QTabWidget`. Each tab should track the current state of each toggleable `QPushButton` which is why I am adding the same object instead of creating new buttons. The position of the widgets doesn't really matter, as long as I have the same `tbutton` object on all tabs. (i.e. when `tbutton` is enabled on Tab 1, it should be enabled on Tabs 2 and 3).

Below is the code I'm using. Note that in this example I'm only showing one toggleable `QPushButton`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTabWidget, QPushButton, QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    tabW = QTabWidget()
    tbutton = QPushButton("foo")
    tbutton.setCheckable(True)

    w1 = QWidget()
    layout1 = QHBoxLayout(w1)
    layout1.addWidget(QPushButton("bar"))
    layout1.addWidget(tbutton)

    w2 = QWidget()
    layout2 = QHBoxLayout(w2)
    layout2.addWidget(QPushButton("baz"))
    layout2.addWidget(tbutton)

    tabW.addTab(w1, "Tab 1")
    tabW.addTab(w2, "Tab 2")
    tabW.addTab(tbutton, "Tab 3")
    tabW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When the app is run, only Tab 3 contains `tbutton`. While it is possible to always show a single button using `QTabWidget`'s `setCornerWidget` method, it is more difficult to modify the layout when the corner widget added is more complicated (i.e. more toggleable buttons).

Comment: Your post is unclear. What does *I need to add to all tabs* mean? Could you explain that in more detail, where should each button be?

Comment: Probably, you want to reparent the button every time you change pages with button.[setParent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setParent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Widgets cannot be "shared" between parents and/or shown multiple times. Every time you add a widget to a new layout, then it will be removed from the previous.

While you *could* reparent the widget by adding it to the layout everytime the tab is changed, it's really not a practical solution, especially if complex layout systems are involved, and reparenting is normally used only in very specific cases where it's *really* important to use the same instance elsewhere due to its complex state (for instance, a toolbar). Since you're just using a button, there's little point in reusing the same instance.

A more logical and safe solution is to create a button for every tab and link their state using signals, then if you also need to connect the toggled signal to another function, do it to just to one of them (not all):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    tabW = QTabWidget()

    w1 = QWidget()
    layout1 = QHBoxLayout(w1)
    layout1.addWidget(QPushButton("bar"))
    tbutton1 = QPushButton("foo", checkable=True)
    layout1.addWidget(tbutton1)

    w2 = QWidget()
    layout2 = QHBoxLayout(w2)
    layout2.addWidget(QPushButton("baz"))
    tbutton2 = QPushButton("foo", checkable=True)
    layout2.addWidget(tbutton2)

    tbutton3 = QPushButton("foo", checkable=True)

    tabW.addTab(w1, "Tab 1")
    tabW.addTab(w2, "Tab 2")
    tabW.addTab(tbutton3, "Tab 3")

    buttons = tbutton1, tbutton2, tbutton3
    def toggleButtons(state):
        for button in buttons:
            button.setChecked(state)
    for button in buttons:
        button.toggled.connect(toggleButtons)

    tabW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The above indication is because the code as it's written triggers some level of recursion, as the signal will be emitted for all `setChecked` calls on buttons that have a different state. Since Qt is well written, all state changes emit signals only when the new state is actually different, but if you want to do things more *correctly*, just block the signals temporarily:

```
def toggleButtons(state):
    for button in buttons:
        blocked = button.blockSignals(True)
        button.setChecked(state)
        button.blockSignals(blocked)
```

But, the best solution is to use [QSignalBlocker](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalblocker.html) which does almost the same thing, but in a safer fashion:

```
def toggleButtons(state):
    for button in buttons:
        with QtCore.QSignalBlocker(button):
            button.setChecked(state)
```

This has a catch: since the signal will then be only emitted once, for the button that has actually triggered, if you need to do something else when the state changes, you either do it in `toggleButtons` or you connect the function to *all* buttons.

If you want to separate the logic of "group toggling" from the actual function that reacts to the state change, a better solution is to use a custom signal, but you must use a class.

```
class TabWidget(QTabWidget):
    stateChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    tabW = TabWidget()

    # ...

    buttons = tbutton1, tbutton2, tbutton3
    def toggleButtons(state):
        for button in buttons:
            with QtCore.QSignalBlocker(button):
                button.setChecked(state)
        tabW.stateChanged.emit(state)

    for button in buttons:
        button.toggled.connect(toggleButtons)

    def doSomething(state):
        print('state changed', state)

    tabW.stateChanged.connect(doSomething)

    tabW.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

<sup>Please consider that this "procedural" flow is fine for educational purposes, but using a class and implement both UI and logic in it is usually a better practice, and the above functions should then become methods in that class so that they can act in the context of the instace.</sup>

Comment: The signal-blocker seems required, rather than just correct. Without it, the slot will be called three times in your first example. For the slot to be truly useful, it must do something other than merely sync the check-state - but preferrably only once.

Comment: @ekhumoro I agree, that's why I specified that if the state change was required to do *something else*, it should only be connected to just one of the button's toggle signal in the first case. I'll edit and clarify, thanks.